# LEFT,RIGHT,INTERSECTION in type script arrays

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays

```
const arr1 = [{id: 1,name: 'Diego', age: 23,}, 
              {id: 2,name: 'Brian',age: 18,}, 
              {id: 4,name: 'Lonaro', age: 21,}];


const arr2 = [{id: 1,name: 'Diego',age: 23,}, 
              {id: 2,name: 'Brian',age: 18,}, 
              {id: 3,name: 'Pikachu',age: 88,}];
```

Need to get arr1 LEFT OUTER JOIN arr2  = [{id: 4,name: 'Lonaro', age: 21,}]

and Need to get arr1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN arr2 = [{id: 3,name: 'Pikachu',age: 88,}]

and Need to get arr1 INTERSECTION arr2 = [{id: 1,name: 'Diego', age: 23,}, 
                  {id: 2,name: 'Brian',age: 18,},]

using typescript

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a difference(x, y) method
2. Use a difference(y, x) method - note that the arrays order is reversed
3. Use an intersection(x, y) method

You can find them in [lodash](https://lodash.com) or [ramdajs](http://ramdajs.com) or roll out [yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356504/javascript-object-array-difference-and-intersection-of-elements).