# Typescript : Find common objects from two array using Lambda function

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am using Typescript for below problem. I want to search object not simple alphabetic or number in the list.

Below are the two arrays.
I want to get common objects in separate list **without using any third party library.**

```js
    firstArray = [
           {
               "id": 4,
               "name": "Tata"
           },
           {
               "id": 11,
               "name": "Maruti"
           },
           {
               "id": 14,
               "name": "Mahindra"
           }
        ]

        secondArray = [
           {
               "id": 4,
               "name": "Tata"
           },
           {
               "id": 11,
               "name": "Maruti"
           },
           {
               "id": 15,
               "name": "Hyundai"
           },
           {
               "id": 21,
               "name": "Honda"
           } 
        ]
        
// Get Common Elements
// I am getting blank array as output

        console.log(firstArray.filter(( make ) => secondArray.includes( make)));
```

Is there good function or way to find out commons element?

Comment: Unless you use types and have a question related to them it's a **Javascript** question.

Comment: @Mörre i was just trying out available options anyway I want to make this in typescript only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript object array difference and intersection of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356504/javascript-object-array-difference-and-intersection-of-elements)

Comment: @Ronnie Does not matter, it's Javascript (ECMAScript).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` with `array#some`. For each object in the first array, check if `id` and `name` exist in the other array.

```js
const firstArray = [{ "id": 4, "name": "Tata" }, { "id": 11, "name": "Maruti" }, { "id": 14, "name": "Mahindra" } ], 
      secondArray = [{ "id": 4, "name": "Tata" }, { "id": 11, "name": "Maruti" }, { "id": 15, "name": "Hyundai" }, { "id": 21, "name": "Honda" } ],
      result = firstArray.filter(o => secondArray.some(({id,name}) => o.id === id && o.name === name));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For ES6, you can also try sets,

For demonstration,

```
const thirdArray = [...new Set([...firstArray ,...secondArray])];
```

Comment: purpose of the your code is different. It is union but without duplicates. I want to create new array with common objects from arrays

Comment: Just tested it but sadly it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone is wishing that extra parameters of 2nd array should be merged into the first array then here is the code:

---

```js
const firstArray = [{ "id": 4, "name": "Tata" }, { "id": 11, "name": "Maruti" }, { "id": 14, "name": "Mahindra" }]

const secondArray = [{ "id": 4, "name": "Tata", "new": 1, junk: "as" }, { "id": 11, "name": "Maruti", "new": 2, junk: "as1" }, { "id": 15, "name": "Hyundai", "new": 3, junk: "asdds" }, { "id": 21, "name": "Honda", junk: "asasd" }]

const newArr =[]
const result = firstArray.filter(o => secondArray.some((sitm) => o.id === sitm.id && newArr.push({
    new: sitm.id,
    //add more fields if needed
    ...o
})));

console.log("*** final result ***", newArr);
```

**Note**: *result* is the just the common part of both arrays and *newArr* is common part plus the attributes you need from second array.