# atleast one of the value's in the array1 obj "data" array matches the "data" array in array2 object

Tags: javascript, arrays

> at least one of the value's in the array1 obj "data" array matches the "data" array in array2 object

```
> array1

array1 = [
  {
      id: '1',
      name: 'ron',
      data: ['p1']
  },
  {
      id: '2',
      name: 'lon',
      data: ['p2']
  },
{
      id: '3',
      name: 'voon',
      data: ['p4']
  }
];


> array2

array2 = [
  {
      id: '1',
      name: 'fgr',
      data:['p1','p2','p3']
  },
  {
      id: '2',
      name: 'gone',
      data:['p1','p2','p3']
  }
]
```

> output:   {
> id: '1',
> name: 'ron',
> data: ['p1']
> },
> {
> id: '2',
> name: 'lon',
> data: ['p2']
> }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356504/difference-and-intersection-of-two-arrays-containing-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below assumption:

- `array1` has objects each of which always have prop `data` which is an array
- `array2` also has objects and these objects will always have prop `data` which is an array as well
- the desired objective is to generate an array with objects from `array1` whose `data` have at least one common element with any of the `data` of `array2` objects.

this solution may work:

```
const findNeedleInHaystack = (needle = array1, haystack = array2) => (
    needle.reduce((acc, itm) => (
      haystack
      .map(x => x.data)
      .flat()
      .some(x => itm.data.includes(x))
        ? [...acc, itm]
        : [...acc]
    ), [])
);
```

**Explanation**

- iterate over the `needle` array (ie, array1) using `.reduce`
- use `.map` on `haystack` array (ie, array2) to separate the `data` from each object
- use `.flat()` to transform the 2-dimensional resulting array into 1-dimension
- use `.some` to see if any element in the 1-dimensional array is also present in `itm`'s `data` array
- if found, concatenate `itm` to the result (using `...` spread operator on `acc` - the aggregator/accumulator)
- if not found, skip concatenating `itm`.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const array1 = [
  {
      id: '1',
      name: 'ron',
      data: ['p1']
  },
  {
      id: '2',
      name: 'lon',
      data: ['p2']
  },
{
      id: '3',
      name: 'voon',
      data: ['p4']
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
      id: '1',
      name: 'fgr',
      data:['p1','p2','p3']
  },
  {
      id: '2',
      name: 'gone',
      data:['p1','p2','p3']
  }
];

const findNeedleInHaystack = (needle = array1, haystack = array2) => (
    needle.reduce((acc, itm) => (
    haystack.map(x => x.data).flat().some(x => itm.data.includes(x))
        ? [...acc, itm]
      : [...acc]
  ), [])
);

console.log(findNeedleInHaystack());
```